# How do i use TfidfVectorizer in 2 steps, incrementing the number of analyzed texts?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I am working on a Text-Classification problem, in Python3, using sklearn.

I am doing the following steps:

1. Clean up all Texts to train the Classifier
2. Extract the features of the training-texts and vectorize using TfidfVectorizer
3. Generate the Classifier (RandomForestClassifier)

This works quite well, now when I get a new Text that I would like to classify, what is the best way to process it? I understand that Tfidf method also looks at the occurrence of the features in the other data-sets, thats's why I am now applying TfidfVectorizer to the old dataset+the new text.
But is there a way I can do it in a kind of incremental way?
So that once the Training-set it does not get touched anymore. 
Would that make sense?

Thank you in advance for your help!
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectorizer is fit based on the corpus of documents you pass. Generally if you are working with a large corpus of documents you will fit the vectorizer to the entire corpus first. This allows the vectorizer to correctly assert the frequency of terms in the documents and appropriately apply the `min_df`, `max_df`, and `max_features` parameters. Once a vectorizer has been fit you can then simply transform a document to extract the tfidf vectors. (This document does not have to be in the training corpus)

For example:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction import TfidfVectorizer

class Tokenizer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    def __call__(self, doc):
        return [self.stemmer.stem(w) for w in word_tokenize(doc)]
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_features=500, lowercase=True, tokenizer=Tokenizer)
# raw_docs can be collection of documents i.e. list, generator, etc...
raw_docs = ['The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog', 'Carlos made a quick jumping catch in the game last night', 'How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood']
tfidf.fit(raw_docs[:1])
tfidf.vocabulary_
{'quick': 5, 'red': 6, 'fox': 2, 'jump': 3, 'lazi': 4, 'brown': 0, 'dog': 1}
# Notice only the first sentence in vocab
tfidf.transform(raw_docs[1:2]).todense()
matrix([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.70710678, 0.        ,
         0.70710678, 0.        ]])
#Vectorizing the second sentence only gives scores for 'jump' and 'quick'
tfidf.fit(raw_docs)
tfidf.vocabulary_
{'quick': 10,
 'red': 11,
 'fox': 5,
 'jump': 7,
 'lazi': 8,
 'brown': 0,
 'dog': 4,
 'carlo': 1,
 'catch': 2,
 'game': 6,
 'night': 9,
 'wood': 12,
 'woodchuck': 13,
 'chuck': 3}
# Notice terms from each sentence now
matrix([[0.        , 0.44036207, 0.44036207, 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.44036207, 0.3349067 , 0.        , 0.44036207,
         0.3349067 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
# We now have twice the features 14 v 7 and the vector catches each of the terms in the sentence.
```

Comment: ah ok that explains quite a bit. I was using fit_transform, didn't know that there is actually fit() and transform(). That answer my question, thanks a lot!

Comment: @LucaB Documentation and source are always your best bet. In this case [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) and [Text Feature Extraction](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction) in the User Guide are very helpful.